# Derivative node in kapacitor batch

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I am using derivative node to calculate bandwidth utilization of network devices, below is the script.

I am using where clause because i wanted alert for specific interface  for specific Ip.

```
// database
var database = 'router'

// measurement from where data is coming
var measurement = 'cisco_router'

// RP from where data is coming
var RP = 'autogen'

// which influx cluster to use
var clus = 'network'

// durations
var period = 7m

var every = 10s

// alerts
var crit = 320

var alertName = 'cisco_router_bandwidth_alert'

var triggerType = 'threshold'

batch
|query(''' SELECT (mean("bandwidth_in") * 8) as "value" FROM "router"."autogen"."cisco_router" where  host = '10.1.11.1' and ( interface_name = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/0' or  interface_name = 'GigabitEthernet0/0/1')  ''')
    .cluster('network')
    .period(7m)
    .every(6m)
    .groupBy(*)
|derivative('value')
    .unit(1s)
    .nonNegative()
    .as('value')
|alert()
    .crit(lambda: "value" > crit)
    .stateChangesOnly()
    .message(' {{.Level}}  for {{ index .Tags "device_name" }} on Port {{ index .Tags "name" }} {{ .Time.Local.Format "2006.01.02 - 15:04:05" }} ')
    .details('''

 <pre>
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 CLIENT NAME : XXXXXXXX
 ENVIRONMENT : Prod
 DEVICE TYPE : Router
 CATEGORY : {{ index .Tags "type" }}
 IP ADDRESS : {{ index .Tags "host" }}
 DATE : {{ .Time.Local.Format "2006.01.02 - 15:04:05" }}
 INTERFACE NAME : {{ index .Tags "name" }}
 VALUE : {{ index .Fields "value" }}
 SEVERITY : {{.Level}}
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 </pre>

''')
    .log('/tmp/chronograf/cisco_router_interface_alert.log')
    .levelTag('level')
    .idTag('id')
    .messageField('message')
    .email()
    .to('XXXXXXX')
|influxDBOut()
    .database('chronograf')
    .retentionPolicy(RP)
    .measurement('alerts')
    .tag('alertName', alertName)
```

But it is not showing anything when i do kapacitor watch and not showing any errors in logs.

Answer (score 0):

derivative() and some other nodes like stateDuration() kind of resets their state on each new batch query, in opposite to stream mode, where their state is kept whole time.

Actually, it is because in batch mode this nodes designed to track changes only inside the current batch of points.

Since your query returns single point - there is no result from derivative().

Try move derivative to the query. And use |httpOut() node to track results on each step - really helpful to understand kapacitor logic.

here is some example:

```
dbrp "telegraf"."autogen"
var q= batch
    |query('SELECT derivative(mean("bytes_recv"), 1s) AS "bytes_recv_1s" FROM "telegraf"."autogen"."net" WHERE time < now() AND "interface"=\'eth0\' GROUP BY time(10m) fill(none)')
        .period(10m)
        .every(30s).align()
        .groupBy(time(10m))
        .fill('none')
    |last('bytes_recv_1s').as('value')
    |httpOut('query')
```

Note, there is a bugs associated with query parsing, that requires specify GROUP BY in both query and tick
https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/971
https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/622

Comment: Hi, could you make the changes in above script as i am unable to understand what you meant by moving derivative to query